# The difference between atom and spyder

Tags: python, atom-editor, spyder

I use atom and spyder to compile the same code. But I got two different result from these two IDEs.

My code is:

```
import tushare as ts
data=ts.get_k_data('002722',start='2017-01-01',end='2017-03-01')
print(data)
```

When I was using spyder, I can get correct result, this is the data of the stock market.
But when compile this code in atom, my error is:

```
nonnumeric port: '1080;DIRECT'
nonnumeric port: '1080;DIRECT'
nonnumeric port: '1080;DIRECT'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\wenzh\python\new.py", line 3, in <module>
data=ts.get_k_data('002722',start='2017-01-01',end='2017-03-01')
File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tushare\stock\trading.py", line 679, in 
get_k_data
data = data[(data.date >= start) & (data.date <= end)]
File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2744, in 
__getattr__
return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'date'
```

What is the problem, why did I get completely different result from these two IDE?

Comment: How exactly did you your code in Atom vs Spyder? Did you run your code in atom through the terminal?

Comment: Yes, I copy the code in spyder to the atom. I am not running my code in terminal, I run my code in ide in both environment

Comment: Can you try running the script you wrote in atom from the terminal? `cd` to your script's directory and run `python your_script.py`? If that works, there might be issues with how Atom sees libraries or runs scripts.